# Is it possible to let several lexers share same ident definitions?

Tags: ocaml, lex, lexical-analysis, ocamllex

I have several lexers: `lexer_1.mll`, `lexer_2.mll`, ...

Some definitions of `ident` (`let ident = regexp`) are common and repeated in these files. For instance, the definition of `INTEGER`, `FLOAT`, ...

Does anyone know if it is possible to define them the once for all somewhere, and let the `.mll` files call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no "pure OCaml" solution, as `ident` seems to be systematically inlined by `ocamllex`. You can still put your regexp definition in a file, and use `cpp` (or any other C pre-processor) to `#include` it wherever needed though. This is of course an abuse of `cpp`, as you're not feeding it with `.c` file, but you wouldn't be the first one to do that.

As a matter of fact, I've just come across [cppo](http://mjambon.com/cppo.html), a cpp-like utility targetting OCaml programs, that you might find useful.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain a little bit more "use good ol' `cpp` to `#include`"?

Comment: cpp is the C preprocessor. You could use the C preprocessor's `#include` directive to do what you want by textual inclusion. Most systems define a program `cpp` for using the preprocessor independently of the C compiler. It's not uncommon to use it this way, despite some small inconveniences of lexical disagreement.

Comment: Jeffrey Scofield has perfectly answered to your comment. I've edited the answer and added a link to an pre-processor that target OCaml files.